# Text in <button> tag bumping to 2 lines on Blackberry (Torch)

Tags: html, css, blackberry

I have a  tag with the text "Click Here" in it, the word wrapping is weird as it displays on separate lines.

This is using a Blackberry Torch...the same button shows up perfectly on an iPhone4 and Android on one line.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use `&nbsp;` instead of a space (non-breaking space).

Or use CSS:

```
#yourbuttonid //or other CSS selector
{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the Torch have a narrower screen than the others?

Anyway, you can use a sticky space instead of a normal space. Or use CSS to disable word wrapping.